# php Error Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt::bind_param()

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this code

```
public function bind_array($array) {
    $array=[1,"bob"];
    $type = '';

    foreach ( $array as $var ) {
        switch (true) {
            case is_int ( $var ) :
                $type .= "i";
                break;
            case is_double ( $var ) :
                $type .= "d";
            default :
                $type .= "s";
        }
    }

    $param_array [] = &$type;

    for($i = 0; $i < count ( $array ); $i ++) {
        $param_array [] = &$array [$i];
    }

    call_user_func ( array ($this->stmt,'bind_param' ), $param_array );
}
```

and I always get the error wrong parameter count. What is the mistake here?

If I change the last line into

```
call_user_func ( array ($this->stmt,'bind_param' ), 'is',1,"bob" );
```

Everything is ok.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `call_user_func_array` instead of `call_user_func` since you're passing an array.

```
call_user_func_array ( array ($this->stmt,'bind_param' ), $param_array );
```

Here are the [official docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php).